# What is the purpose of Windows + Spacebar?

Tags: windows, windows-7, desktop, preview

I understand that on **Windows 7** you can use the key combination <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to 'preview the desktop'.

However, I don't see a valuable purpose for this, as you cannot manipulate anything during the preview.  To me, it is simply eye candy to view where your windows are located and what your desktop background image is.

It would be nice to start applications from the preview, but this is not possible.<sup>1</sup>

So, does anyone know if there is a purpose besides the eye candy that I mentioned?

---

**1:** <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> works for showing the desktop; however if an application is started, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> cannot be used to show all of the previously minimized windows unless the user enters the key combination before the new application's window display.

Also, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (mimize windows) and <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (show all previously minimized windows) can be used to display all windows after starting an application from the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

It could be useful if you have an application like rainmeter running on the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

In XP they introduced 'Widgets,' I think it's primarily for viewing them.

Comment: +1 - I see, I normally don't use widgets.  That could explain why I didn't know about that function. :)

Comment: To be frank, I'm not sure anyone does, except people who don't know how to turn them off.

Comment: They were a security risk - Microsoft abruptly stopped supporting them some years back, for that reason.

Comment: As a power user, I personally wouldn't like to use widgets since it clutters the desktop.  If it is a widget for displaying the time/weather/news, I would look it up through other means.  However, I can see a casual user benefiting from these types of widgets, yet most casual users don't know about shortcut keys :P